# Nodejs, return condition not working

Tags: node.js

I am new to Nodejs. I am trying to return data. after select query. Here i am writing two condition's. first is very simple in logic and it is working but let me know why second condition is not working.

**First Condition:**

```
var arr =  {email:"john@gmail.com", password:"};  
return arr;

databaseConnection.query("SELECT * FROM users where email = '"+email+"' and password = '"+password +"'", function (err, result) {

 });
```

**Second Condition**

```
databaseConnection.query("SELECT * FROM users where email = '"+email+"' and password = '"+password +"'", function (err, result) {     

var arr =  {email:"john@gmail.com", password:"};  
return arr;

});
```

from **passport.js**

```
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;
var configAuth = require('./auth');


module.exports = function(passport,databaseConnection) {

    var usermodule   = require('../models/user')(databaseConnection);

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user);
    });

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user);
    });

passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({

        usernameField : 'username',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback

    },
    function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form

            var user={};


                var result = usermodule.login(email,password);

                    console.log('usercraeted');
                    user["email"]=email;
                    user["status"]=true;
                    user["name"]="John Snow";
                    user["avatar"]="";
                    user["loginStatus"]=true;
                    return done(null, user);

                user["msg"]="invalide email";
                console.log("out");


            return done(null, false,user["msg"]);
        };

    );

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, the code is executed up to this point:

```
var arr =  {email:"john@gmail.com", password:"};  
return arr;

// interpreter exits and `{email:"john@gmail.com", password:"}` is returned,
// `databaseConnection.query("` is never executed
```

In your second example, the code is executed up to this point:

```
databaseConnection.query("SELECT * FROM users where email = '"+email+"' and password = '"+password +"'", function (err, result) {     

var arr =  {email:"john@gmail.com", password:"};  
return arr;

});
// interpreter exits, undefined is returned
```

Comment: how to return results from database ?

Comment: @SyedDaniyalAsif, where is this code running? where do you want to return the result to? post full code.

Comment: please check it

Comment: @SyedDaniyalAsif, still not full code. Where is the method `login`? How is `databaseConnection` created?

Comment: yes please check it

Answer (score 0):

The second condition doesn't work because node.js is asynchronous. And your return is on a callback that take some times to be executed.

Comment: so how to execute my code ?

Comment: What do you exactly want to do ?

Comment: You can directly use function inside your callback

Comment: I am calling this function from other page. it returns undefined... i want to get results from database and return results... results exists in array... as i found in console... but returned results are undefined on other page where i am calling function

Answer (score 0):

You have to use callbacks.

```
function getUser() {
   var email = "test@test.com";
   var password = "test";
   getDatas(email, password, function(err, result) {
       // the result is good and not undefined if no errors :)
   });
}

function getDatas(email, password, callback) {

   databaseConnection.query("SELECT * FROM users where email = '"+email+"' and password = '"+password +"'", function (err, result) {     
       callback(err, result); // callback is executed with the result you
   });
}
```

Hope I helped you